# Parallel::ForkManager don't want to spawn new children after MAX

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork

Sorry for my english...

OK, the problem.
I'm using Parallel::ForkManager to limit fork processes in my PERL script.

example:

```
$pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(3);

[...]
while ($new_client = $httpdaemon->accept())
{
    $pm->start and next;

    # do smth with request in here

    $pm->finish;
}
```

I see children are forking OK, and they are ending OK - but i can't process more requests than MAX - 3 in this case.

On 4th request (after prev. 3), script don't want to spawn new child (it hangs)

? Parallel::ForkManager->new(3) - this means - MAX 3 at the same time, right?

You know - i want to process 3 remote clients at the same time, and after they completes - do the same with other 3.

If i don't find any solution, i'll use Proc::Queue instead....

Comment: how do you know the children are ending OK?  sure sounds like they aren't

Answer (score 1):

> On 4th request (after prev. 3), script don't want to spawn new child (it hangs)

Yes, it hangs until one of the original three finishes, after which the fourth will be started. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: Not really. Those 3 forks are finished on the system and script wont spawn more after those 3.

Comment: Either they're not finished, or there's no connection to `accept`. If there is, then another child is spawned immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time guys.
I did some more debugging and I have found the solution.

The problem was in:
        $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';

At the front on the script.
If this SIG is set to IGNORE PM freaks out.

Thank you.